# Shared data between windows in Electron

Tags: electron

I need a multi-window app to share media streams. Is there anyway to do that? In nw.js I can create a proof of concept, where a MediaStream created in one window can be played in the other, but it appears I cannot do this in Electron. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

I know for certain that it's possible with WebRTC to stream audio/video from a MediaStream to another window process. Been there, done that, based on the [electron-peer-connection](https://github.com/han-gyeol/electron-peer-connection) library (it makes the process quite easy, actually).

Unfortunately, [there are a *lot* of limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48791065/uncompressed-unencrypted-unaltered-raw-transfer-of-real-time-pcm-audio-data-t) to consider if you take this approach (WebRTC will compress your audio with lossy compression, you'll have a big latency, an Electron bug currently causes the audio to become mono, things like that).

So this is fine for things like voice, but not for e.g. high-end native-quality audio processing.

---

Additionally, if your app is not a monster beast with insane performance requirements, you can also use Web Audio API and a ScriptProcessorNode (AudioWorklet is still not available in Electron) to access audio sample data from the MediaStream directly, and send that over with standard electron-IPC.

You can then rebuild the MediaStream in the other window process using Web Audio API and MediaStreamDestinationNode.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the same issue and have tried out almost all the methods. One way to do this is to use the nativeWindow in electron, with react create a portal and open in it a native window with window.open(), this will give us a electron window without browserwindow features, to use browserwindow features, we have to convert the native window to a browserwindow and the only way I found to do it is with the newGuest event in "new-window" unfortunately this got deprecated and newGuest event is not available but it would work in versions below 22.

```html
mainWindow.webContents.on('new-window',
(event, url, frameName, disposition, options, additionalFeatures) =>
{
// This is the name we chose for our window. You can have multiple names for
// multiple windows and each have their options
if (frameName === 'NewWindowComponent ') {
event.preventDefault();
Object.assign(options, {
// This will prevent interactions with the mainWindow
parent: mainWindow,
width: 300,
height: 300,
// You can also set left and top positions
});
event.newGuest = new BrowserWindow(options);
let newWindow = event.newGuest
}
});
```

Now you can access newWindow as a BrowserWindow and  this will work.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to communicate between windows using the `ipc module` by emitting events through `main process` and add `listeners` for them in the windows.

Comment: I'm familiar with that idea, but does that work for live MediaStreams?

Comment: I guess I thought that was only useful for JSON style data.