# Uncompressed, unencrypted, unaltered, raw transfer of real-time PCM audio data through WebRTC stream

Tags: javascript, webrtc, electron, web-audio-api

I'm transferring a *live* audio stream between 2 Electron window processes using WebRTC. There are no ICE or STUN servers, or anything like that, the connection is established manually through Electron IPC communication (based on [this code](https://github.com/han-gyeol/electron-peer-connection/blob/master/index.js)).

*Note: from the technical point of view regarding the audio streams themselves, this is very similar (if not identical) to streaming between 2 browser tabs on the same domain, so this is primarily not a question regarding Electron itself, although Electron IPC would be obviously substituted with a browser equivalent.*

The audio stream works, I can transmit audio from one window to another in real-time, as it is generated. That is, I can generate audio (Web Audio API) in window "A" and listen to it through an `<audio>` element in window "B", or do processing on it using a separate AudioContext in window "B" (although there is some latency).

However, the audio data is *vastly* altered during streaming: it became mono, its quality dropped, and there is significant latency. After fiddling around I've learned WebRTC does pretty much *everything* I don't need, including encoding the audio stream with an audio codec, encrypting the transfer, running echo cancellation, and so on.

**I don't need these. I need to simply transfer raw audio data through *local* WebRTC without altering the audio in *any* way. It needs to be float32 accurate to the sample.**

How can I do this with WebRTC?

---

### Why use WebRTC then?

I need to do custom audio processing inside the Web Audio API.

The only way to do this is using a [ScriptProcessorNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ScriptProcessorNode), which is unusuable in production code when there's essentially *anything* on the page, because it is broken by design (it processes audio on the UI thread, and causes audio glitching by even slight UI interactions).

So basically, because of this (and to the best of my knowledge), my only option is to transfer audio with WebRTC streams to another window process, perform ScriptProcessorNode processing there (nothing more is happening in that window, empty DOM, so the processing is always nice and smooth), then send the results back.

This works, but the audio is altered during streaming, which I want to avoid (see above).

---

### Why not use AudioWorklet?

Because Electron is 5 versions behind Chrome unfortunately (version 59 at the moment), and simply does not ship `AudioWorklet` yet.

Comment: Why no send the raw buffers that you use with WAAPI via web sockets? You can setup a round robin loop on the receiving end which is filled when data is received.

Comment: @K3N -- Wouldn't that require using a `ScriptProcessorNode` once again?

Comment: To clarify: communicating between processes is not the problem. I could easily set up socket connections to transfer sample blocks, but that requires audio data to hop onto the main thread, which is a no-go in a non-trivial application. The data transfer must originate from the audio thread.

Comment: You can use web sockets from a worker which could offload the main thread (using transferable objects/typed arrays). The challenge with WebRTC is that audio *will* be encoded (audio/rtx) and sent as frames in RTP packets from what I can remember. Another possible option is to perhaps use the data channel of WebRTC.

Comment: @K3N -- You can't get the audio data to a web worker without first moving it from the audio thread to the main thread using the `ScriptProcessorNode`, because `AudioContext` does not work in worker threads.

Comment: The ScriptProcessorNode is accurate to the bit. We use it for recording in a product aimed at VO and broadcast. The problem is likely in the timing of your own code.

Comment: @Someone -- You are correct, but (1) ScriptProcessorNode is no longer relevant, as recent versions of electron ship standards-compliant AudioWorklet support, (2) the timing issues are from unavoidable main-thread load, such as UI rendering and improper implementation of `decodeAudioData` in chromium (see https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=749485). You can fragment UI rendering using cooperative background multitasking, but you are always at a risk of buffer underflow from other sources of blocking in a real-time application.

Comment: (1) Web Audio is still very much a living standard, things get deprecated and reinvented all the time. When you work on an older Chrome version, it's annoying, because you can see it coming, but it happens either way. Such applications will need maintenance for a while. (2) Where does decodeAudioData come into play? The ScriptProcessor already supplies you with the raw sample data. Could you describe what exactly you're trying to accomplish from the product perspective?

Comment: @Someone Sure, the problem is that when you have a full production app (i.e. not a tech demo), you have all sorts of possible blocks on the main thread, which makes it impossible to rely on the timing of the main-thread-driven ScriptProcessorNode. The `decodeAudioData` API, for example, creates an ugly main-thread block when decoding has finished, immediately before the Promise would resolve. The reason for this is detailed in the link above, there is blocking copying involved. This makes it impossible to use ScriptProcessorNode with e.g. `decodeAudioData` in 1 app.

Comment: @Someone But regardless, this question is essentially obsolete, as AudioWorklet solves the problem perfectly.