# How to read audio data from a 'MediaStream' object in a C++ addon

Tags: javascript, c++, electron, v8, blink

After sweating blood and tears I've finally managed to set up a Node C++ addon and shove a web-platform standard `MediaStream` object into one of its C++ methods for good. For compatibility across different V8 and Node.js versions, I'm using [Native Abstractions for Node.js (nan)](https://github.com/nodejs/nan):

**addon.cc**

```
NAN_METHOD(SetStream)
{
    Nan::HandleScope scope;
    v8::Local<v8::Object> mediaStream = info[0]->ToObject();
}
```

**addon.js**

```
setStream(new MediaStream());
```

For what it's worth, this works correctly (i.e. it does not obliterate the renderer process on sight), and I can verify the presence of the `MediaStream` object, e.g. by returning its constructor name from the C++ method:

**addon.cc**

```
info.GetReturnValue().Set(mediaStream->GetConstructorName());
```

When called from JavaScript through `setStream`, this would return the string *`MediaStream`*, so the object is definitely there. I can also return the `mediaStream` object itself and everything will work correctly, so it's indeed the object I need.

**So, how would I read audio data (i.e. audio samples) from this `MediaStream` object in C++?** As a sidenote, the actual data read (and processing) would be done in a separate `std::thread`.

---

### Bounty Update

I understand this would be sort of easier/possible if I were compiling Electron and/or Chromium myself, but I'd rather not get involved in that maintenance hell.

I was wondering if it would be possible without doing that, and as far as my research goes, I'm convinced I need 2 things to get this done:

1. The relevant header files, for which I believe [blink public](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink-public/) should be adequate
2. A chromium/blink library file (?), to resolve external symbols, similarly to the node.dylib file

Also, as I said, I believe I could compile chromium/blink myself and then I would have this lib file, but that would be a maintenance hell with Electron. With this in mind, I believe this question ultimately comes down to a C++ linking question. Is there any other approach to do what I'm looking for?

#### Edit

ScriptProcessorNode is not an option in my case, as its performance makes it nearly unusable in production. This would require to process audio samples on the ui/main thread, which is absolutely insane.

#### Edit 2

[AudioWorklets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioWorklet) have been available in Electron for some time now, which, unlike the ScriptProcessorNode (or worse, the AnalyzerNode), is low-latency and very reliable for true C++ backed audio processing even in real time.

If someone wants to go ahead and write an AudioWorklet-based answer, I'll gladly accept, but beware: it's a *very* advanced field and a very deep rabbit hole, with countless obstacles to get through even before a very simple, general-purpose pass-through prototype (especially so because currently in Electron, Atomics-synced, buffered cross-thread audio processing is required to pull this off because https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/22503 -- although getting a native C++ addon into one audio renderer thread, let alone multiple threads at the same time, is probably equally as challenging).

Comment: I'm not getting your question. but u can check these two : https://github.com/common-tater/wkwebview-getusermedia-shim/blob/master/WKWebViewGetUserMediaShim/WKWebViewGetUserMediaShim.m     ...    http://realtimeweekly.co/how-to-use-webrtc-in-your-ios-projects-part-ii/

Comment: @nullqube I've been checking out WebRTC for this task, but it seems it's [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48791065/uncompressed-unencrypted-unaltered-raw-transfer-of-real-time-pcm-audio-data-t) to stream raw, uncompressed audio. If it was possible, I could simply start a new Electron window process, stream audio there, do ScriptProcessorNode-based processing in that separate window process, and stream back. But there's always significant amounts of lossy compression _hardcoded_ into WebRTC, as well as very high latency.

Comment: does this help? https://discuss.atom.io/t/multiple-streaming-recording-in-media-recorder/54239

Comment: Did you try using `WebWorker` on the JavaScript side to transfer your work into "background thread" then call the C++ part from it??

Comment: Have you tried WebAssemby

Comment: I'm not an expert in node bindings, but from what I found in existing addons, did you try something like:
```v8::Local<v8::Value> method = Nan::Get(obj, Nan::New<String>("getTracks").ToLocalChecked()).ToLocalChecked();
Nan::MaybeLocal<v8::Value> result = Nan::CallAsFunction(method->ToObject(), obj , 0, NULL);``` to call js methods of objects?

Comment: @WlodzislavK. The problem is that accessing MediaStream samples is not a JS exposed as a JS method, because it's not part of the web API.

Comment: Its not possible by doing it just with the V8 API.
If you're capable of knowing the Blink engine version of your electron or chromium version, then you could add a AudioDestinationConsumer to the source of one of the audio tracks on the media stream.

https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/blink/renderer/platform/mediastream/media_stream_source.h?sq=package:chromium&g=0&l=123

I've currently not yet tested that, but In a few months I will and post a more detailed answer :)

Comment: I think you can't do that from node, you need a browser context, to use the analyzer node of the web audio api. This is a browser native api: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode/getFloatFrequencyData . What you can do is set a local server from your scripts and send the datas from the browser to that server

Comment: You say it comes to down a linker issue / maintenance hell - this is not obvious to me - can you go into more details as to why ?

Answer (score 1):

The MediaStream header is part of Blink's [renderer modules](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink.git/+/master/Source/modules/mediastream/MediaStream.cpp), and it's not obvious to me how you could retrieve this from nan plugin.

So, instead let's look at what you *do* have, namely a [v8::Object](https://v8docs.nodesource.com/node-7.10/db/d85/classv8_1_1_object.html). I believe that v8::Object exposes all the functionality you need, it has:

- GetPropertyNames()
- Get(context, index)
- Set(context, key, value)
- Has(context, key)

Unless you *really* need a strictly defined interface, why not avoid the issue altogether and just use the dynamic type that you already have?

For getting audio data out specifically, you would need to call [getAudioTracks()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream) on the v8::Object, which probably looks something like this?

Note: I don't think you need a context, v8 seems to be happy with it being empty: [v8/src/api/api.cc](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/v8/src/api/api.cc?l=185&gs=kythe%253A%252F%252Fchromium.googlesource.com%252Fchromium%252Fsrc%253Flang%253Dc%25252B%25252B%253Fpath%253Dsrc%252Fv8%252Fsrc%252Fapi%252Fapi.cc%2523PREPARE_FOR_EXECUTION_WITH_CONTEXT%252523m%2525407272&gsn=PREPARE_FOR_EXECUTION_WITH_CONTEXT&ct=xref_usages)

Should look something like this, plus some massaging of types in and out of v8.

```
v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Value> get_audio_tracks = mediaStream->Get("getAudioTracks");
// Maybe needs to be v8::Object or array?
if (!get_audio_tracks.IsEmpty()) {
    v8::Local<v8::Value> audio_tracks = get_audio_tracks.ToLocalChecked()();
}
```